# Assign new columns to a list of dataframes from a second dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, tidyr, purrr

I have a list of dataframes `df_list` and a second dataframe `df_new`. I want to add the 1st column `a` of `df_new` into the 1st dataframe `mtcars1` in the list `df_list`, the 2nd column `b` of `df_new` into the 2nd dataframe `mtcars2` in the list `df_list`, and so on.

The expected result: In the `df_list`, `mtcars1` will have a new column `a` from `df_new`, `mtcars2` will have a new column `b` from `df_new`, `mtcars3` will have a new column `c` from `df_new`, `mtcars4` will have a new column `c` from `df_new`.

What's the best way to do this in a function or loop?

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list <- list(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars, mtcars)
names(df_list) <- c("mtcars1", "mtcars2", "mtcars3", "mtcars4")
df_new <- mtcars[1:4] %>% rename(a = mpg, b = cyl, c = disp, d = hp)
```

Comment: Maybe `Map(cbind, df_list, df_new)` ?

Comment: I got an error on "Error: `.x` must be a vector, not a function" @zx8754

Comment: It is `Map`, not `map`.

Comment: Great. It worked but it has the similar problem from the other answer - it doesn't maintain the original column name. Any way to preserve the column names? @zx8754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Map*:

```
Map(cbind, df_list, df_new)
```

If we need to keep the names, then write custom function:

```
myCbind <- function(x, y){
  d <- cbind(x, df_new[[ y ]])
  colnames(d)[ ncol(d) ] <- y
  d
  }

Map(myCbind, df_list, colnames(df_new))
```

Check the names:

```
res <- Map(myCbind, df_list, colnames(df_new))

sapply(res, function(i) tail(colnames(i), 1))
# mtcars1 mtcars2 mtcars3 mtcars4 
#     "a"     "b"     "c"     "d"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
for(i in 1:4){
  df_list[[i]] = cbind(df_list[[i]], df_new[,i])}
```

Comment: Almost there! The only downside is that I get the column name `df_new[, I]` in every dataframe in the list. Anyway I can maintain the original column name - a, b, c, d?

Comment: You can add `colnames(df_list[[i]])[ncol(df_list[[i]])] = colnames(df_new)[i]` as a new line in the loop, but i'll look into a cleaner way to do it.